# Html relative links not using https with elastic beanstalk

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When my page is loaded with `https` my relative links are still trying to load by http. When i try to go to the script with https the script is there and loads but will not load on the page.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://site-qa-cloned.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://site-qa-cloned.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/public_html/scripts/lib/stripe.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Simple script loading. I have also tried `//public_html...` and it will attempt to find the script at `http://public_html/..` and it will not change protocols.

```
<script src="public_html/scripts/lib/stripe.js"></script>
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: `//public_html` wont work as `//` requires a `FQDN/IP` but the `<script src="public_html/scripts/lib/stripe.js"></script>` should work fine. Do you have a reverse proxy in front?

Comment: We have a AWS Load balancer in front but no reverse proxy.